# JSON.parse is creating null/undefined objects from Google Books API. Can't iterate in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, object, undefined

I'm trying to get certain fields from Google Books (title, authors, etc) by extracting them from a JSON file. I could get the JSON using the request module, however, seems certain nested objects are empty when I console.log the variable I stored the JSON to. The JSON file has all the information I need, just the variable I stored it to doesn't.

I have been trying to turn the JSON into an iterable object that I can get these fields from but seems the data is undefined.

Any suggestions?

```
let finalSearch = website + formatSearch ;


request(finalSearch, function(err, resp, body){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        var fileSaved = false ;

    } else {
        var data = 
        fs.writeFile('./bookData.json', body, err => {
            if (err) throw err;

            console.log('Json Saved');
            var fileSaved = true ;

                if (fileSaved) {
                //bring in json file
                let jsonData = require('./bookData.json');

                let jsonStringed = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
                let jsonParsed = JSON.parse(jsonStringed);

                let keys = Object.keys(jsonParsed);
                let vals = Object.values(jsonParsed);
                let entries = Object.entries(jsonParsed);

                console.log(jsonParsed);


            };

            });

        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Need to do a "deep clone".

fs.writeFile('./bookData.json', **JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body))**, err =>